# back fill missing data with a label for a window of a time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, categorical-data

I want to backfill each column based on time (1 day ,2 day) with different label.
here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
np.random.seed(11) 


date_today = datetime.now()
ndays = 15
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [date_today + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(ndays)], 
                   'test': pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays)),     'test2':pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays))})

df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .7)
print(df) # this will be the dataset that I generate for this question 

# my orginal data set have labels that is why I convert it to str
df['test']=df['test'].astype(str)
df['test2']=df['test2'].astype(str)
df.replace('nan', np.nan, inplace = True)

for I in df.dropna().index.values:
        end=I
        start=end-np.timedelta64(24,'h')
        start2=end-np.timedelta64(48,'h')
        df[(df.index >= start) & (df.index <= end)]=df[(df.index >= start) & (df.index <= end)].bfill()
```

my initial dataset will look like this:

```
                                test     test2
date                                          
2018-03-07 11:28:23.028856       NaN       NaN
2018-03-08 11:28:23.028856       NaN       NaN
2018-03-09 11:28:23.028856 -0.484565  1.574634
2018-03-10 11:28:23.028856 -2.653319       NaN
2018-03-11 11:28:23.028856       NaN       NaN
2018-03-12 11:28:23.028856       NaN       NaN
2018-03-13 11:28:23.028856 -0.536629       NaN
2018-03-14 11:28:23.028856       NaN  0.725752
2018-03-15 11:28:23.028856       NaN  1.549072
2018-03-16 11:28:23.028856 -1.065603  0.630080
2018-03-17 11:28:23.028856       NaN       NaN
2018-03-18 11:28:23.028856 -0.475733  0.732271
2018-03-19 11:28:23.028856       NaN -0.642575
2018-03-20 11:28:23.028856       NaN -0.178093
2018-03-21 11:28:23.028856       NaN -0.573955
```

What I want to get is like this:
I tried different things but I couldn't find a way to this with bfill, bfill don't get any parameters for value and fillna only get method or value.

```
                                test     test2
date                                          
2018-03-07 11:28:23.028856  -0.484565_2D 1.574634_2D
2018-03-08 11:28:23.028856 -0.484565_D   1.574634_D
2018-03-09 11:28:23.028856 -0.484565     1.574634
2018-03-10 11:28:23.028856 -2.653319       NaN
2018-03-11 11:28:23.028856 -0.536629_2D       NaN
2018-03-12 11:28:23.028856 -0.536629_D    0.725752_2D
2018-03-13 11:28:23.028856 -0.536629     0.725752_D
2018-03-14 11:28:23.028856 -1.065603_2D  0.725752
2018-03-15 11:28:23.028856 -1.065603_D   1.549072
2018-03-16 11:28:23.028856 -1.065603     0.630080
2018-03-17 11:28:23.028856 -0.475733_D   0.732271_D
2018-03-18 11:28:23.028856 -0.475733     0.732271
2018-03-19 11:28:23.028856       NaN    -0.642575
2018-03-20 11:28:23.028856       NaN    -0.178093
2018-03-21 11:28:23.028856       NaN    -0.573955
```

**Update:**
The timestamp of my original dataset is non uniform so this code create similar time stamps:

```
date_today = datetime.now()
ndays = 15
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [date_today + timedelta(days=(abs(np.random.randn(1))*2)[0]*x) for x in range(ndays)], 
                   'test': pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays)),     'test2':pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays))})


df1=pd.DataFrame({'date': [date_today + timedelta(hours=x) for x in range(ndays)], 
                   'test': pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays)),     'test2':pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays))})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'date': [date_today + timedelta(days=x)-timedelta(seconds=100*x) for x in range(ndays)], 
                   'test': pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays)),     'test2':pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays))})
df=df.append(df1)
df=df.append(df2)


df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .7)
print(df) # this will be the dataset that I generate for this question 

# my orginal data set have labels that is why I convert it to str
df['test']=df['test'].astype(str)
df['test2']=df['test2'].astype(str)
df.replace('nan', np.nan, inplace = True)
```

I really appreciate if anyone can help me with this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this like backward fill of two days worth of data only?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound yes, that is correct, backward fill of one day and then 2 days in the data that is in the data table.

Comment: why isn't the value `-0.536629` in column `test` at date `2018-03-13 11:28:23.028856` backfilling the two null values in the prior two dates?

Comment: @HaleemurAli It should, it was a typo, I updated the question, thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 1):

create a filled dataframe using fillna with method backfill & limit 2

```
filled = df.fillna(method='bfill', limit=2)
# filled outputs:
                                       test            test2
date
2018-03-07 16:12:25.944362  -0.484565132221     1.5746340731
2018-03-08 16:12:25.944362  -0.484565132221     1.5746340731
2018-03-09 16:12:25.944362  -0.484565132221     1.5746340731
2018-03-10 16:12:25.944362   -2.65331855926              NaN
2018-03-11 16:12:25.944362  -0.536629362235              NaN
2018-03-12 16:12:25.944362  -0.536629362235   0.725752224799
2018-03-13 16:12:25.944362  -0.536629362235   0.725752224799
2018-03-14 16:12:25.944362   -1.06560298045   0.725752224799
2018-03-15 16:12:25.944362   -1.06560298045    1.54907163337
2018-03-16 16:12:25.944362   -1.06560298045   0.630079822493
2018-03-17 16:12:25.944362  -0.475733492683   0.732271353885
2018-03-18 16:12:25.944362  -0.475733492683   0.732271353885
2018-03-19 16:12:25.944362              NaN  -0.642575392433
2018-03-20 16:12:25.944362              NaN  -0.178093175312
2018-03-21 16:12:25.944362              NaN   -0.57395455941
```

create a bool data frame to indicate whether a cell was filled

```
is_filled = df.isnull() & filled.notnull()
# is_filled outputs:
                             test  test2
date
2018-03-07 16:12:25.944362   True   True
2018-03-08 16:12:25.944362   True   True
2018-03-09 16:12:25.944362  False  False
2018-03-10 16:12:25.944362  False  False
2018-03-11 16:12:25.944362   True  False
2018-03-12 16:12:25.944362   True   True
2018-03-13 16:12:25.944362  False   True
2018-03-14 16:12:25.944362   True  False
2018-03-15 16:12:25.944362   True  False
2018-03-16 16:12:25.944362  False  False
2018-03-17 16:12:25.944362   True   True
2018-03-18 16:12:25.944362  False  False
2018-03-19 16:12:25.944362  False  False
2018-03-20 16:12:25.944362  False  False
2018-03-21 16:12:25.944362  False  False
```

create masks to indicate filled values that need suffix `_1D` or `_2D`

```
one_d = (is_filled & ~is_filled.shift(-1).fillna(False)).applymap(lambda x: '_1D' if x else '')
two_d = (is_filled & is_filled.shift(-1).fillna(False)).applymap(lambda x: '_2D' if x else '')
suffix = pd.concat([one_d, two_d]).groupby('date').agg('max')
# suffix outputs: 

                             test test2
date
2018-03-07 16:12:25.944362  _2D   _2D
2018-03-08 16:12:25.944362  _1D   _1D
2018-03-09 16:12:25.944362
2018-03-10 16:12:25.944362
2018-03-11 16:12:25.944362  _2D
2018-03-12 16:12:25.944362  _1D   _2D
2018-03-13 16:12:25.944362        _1D
2018-03-14 16:12:25.944362  _2D
2018-03-15 16:12:25.944362  _1D
2018-03-16 16:12:25.944362
2018-03-17 16:12:25.944362  _1D   _1D
2018-03-18 16:12:25.944362
2018-03-19 16:12:25.944362
2018-03-20 16:12:25.944362
2018-03-21 16:12:25.944362
```

join the suffix dataframe to the filled dataframe convert the float to strings & append the appropriate suffixes

```
final = filled.join(suffix, rsuffix='_x')
final.apply(lambda x: '{}{}'.format(x.test, x.test_x), axis=1)
# outputs:
date
2018-03-07 16:12:25.944362    -0.484565132221_2D
2018-03-08 16:12:25.944362    -0.484565132221_1D
2018-03-09 16:12:25.944362       -0.484565132221
2018-03-10 16:12:25.944362        -2.65331855926
2018-03-11 16:12:25.944362    -0.536629362235_2D
2018-03-12 16:12:25.944362    -0.536629362235_1D
2018-03-13 16:12:25.944362       -0.536629362235
2018-03-14 16:12:25.944362     -1.06560298045_2D
2018-03-15 16:12:25.944362     -1.06560298045_1D
2018-03-16 16:12:25.944362        -1.06560298045
2018-03-17 16:12:25.944362    -0.475733492683_1D
2018-03-18 16:12:25.944362       -0.475733492683
2018-03-19 16:12:25.944362                   nan
2018-03-20 16:12:25.944362                   nan
2018-03-21 16:12:25.944362                   nan
```

similarly you can generate the filled & suffixed series for `test2`. However, I would recommend that you keep `test` & `test2` as numeric types and store the fill & lag information in separate columns (here the column `suffix` stores that info in the dataframe `final`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is an elegant way to do it. The original data set is not uniform in term of the date. so it has dates that are not in a uniform intervals. I implemented to solve this with looping over each column but that might not be efficient. Is there any way to change what you proposed as a solution to be able to deal with non uniform timestamps without resampling.

Comment: Can you show us how the dates are not uniform, there maybe a better way

Comment: I updated the question to create a non uniform timestamps, which have missing days and etc. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I wrote this script that do the job but it is super slow and not feasible for my dataset `for II in list(df):
    for I in df[II].dropna().index.values:
            end=I
            start=end-np.timedelta64(24,'h')
            start2=end-np.timedelta64(48,'h')
            s2=df[(df[II].index >= start) & (df[II].index <= end)]
            s[II]=df[II][(df[II].index >= start) & (df[II].index <= end)].bfill()
            s[II].loc[s2[II].isnull()]=s[II].astype(str).astype(str)+'D'
            df[II][(df[II].index >= start) & (df[II].index <= end)]=s[II]` another loop for 2D

Comment: i can't think of a good way to do it right now, but may be you can consider putting a bounty on this question to attract others to attempt a solution.