# Backfill data a dataframe with nonuniform timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, fillna

**Description**
I have a categorical dataframe which contains nan values at few places. I am trying to perform data cleaning in which I back fill the nan values for 1 day before the label ( error). My dataset look like:

**dataframe**

```
Date                   Error Type 1      Error Type 2   Error Type 3
2010-03-07 13:12:25      NaN                 NaN         NaN
2010-03-08 12:12:25      NaN                 G35         NaN
2010-03-09 15:12:25      P5                  NaN         NaN 
2010-03-10 08:12:25      P5                  NaN         NaN
2010-03-11 12:05:25     NaN                  NaN         F2
2010-06-13 11:06:25      P1                   G1          F1
```

**The dataframe I hope to get**

```
Date                   Error Type 1      Error Type 2       Error Type 3
2010-03-07 10:12:25      NaN                  G35_1          NaN
2010-03-08 12:12:25      P5_1                 G35_1          NaN
2010-03-09 15:12:25      P5_1                 NaN            NaN 
2010-03-10 08:12:25      P5                   NaN            F2_1
2010-03-11 12:05:25      NaN                  NaN            F2_1
2010-06-13 11:06:25      P1                   G1             F1
```

I found similar question [back fill missing data with a label for a window of a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158268/back-fill-missing-data-with-a-label-for-a-window-of-a-time) but didn't have any answer for nonuniform timestamp. My main dataset have over 100 columns too.
I have no idea how to solve this. Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: if you don't have multiple records per day, then you can create a date based index and use [asfreq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html#pandas.DataFrame.asfreq) with '1D' as frequency. You can then use fillna with backfill and delete duplicates based on 'Date' column.

Comment: @Floydian unfortunately, there are multiple records per day, my goal is to get the earliest one  and back propagate one day before it happen. the fillna limit would work if i had a uniform timestampes

Comment: `df.set_index(df['Date'].dt.date, inplace = True)`
`df.asfreq(freq='1D').fillna(method='bfill', limit=1).dropna(how='all').drop_duplicates(keep='last')`

Try something like this. this works on the current data. This code assumes that your Date column is datetime64